# Integer precision in modern Fortran

Tags: fortran, long-integer, iso

The value of `selected_int_kind(int16)` appears to 1 instead of 2. Is this a compiler bug?

In the following output please note the discrepancy for `bint` which is intended to be 2 bytes, `INT16`. (The annotations <=== were added for clarity.)

```
compiler version  = GCC version 5.1.0
compiler options  = -fPIC -mmacosx-version-min=10.9.4 -mtune=core2 -Og -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -Wpedantic -fcheck=bounds -fmax-errors=5
execution command = ./a.out

Number of bytes in type default = 4
Number of bytes in type int_8 = 1
Number of bytes in type int_16 = 2         <===
Number of bytes in type int_32 = 4
Number of bytes in type int_64 = 8
Number of bytes in type int_a = 1
Number of bytes in type int_b = 1          <===
Number of bytes in type int_c = 2
Number of bytes in type int_d = 4
Value of aint = 1
Value of bint = 1                          <===
Value of cint = 2
Value of dint = 4
Value of selected_int_kind ( INT16 ) = 1   <===
```

The following code is supplied to allow readers to investigate this problem. The assignment in question is in line 13.

```
program bytes
    use iso_fortran_env
    implicit NONE

    integer           :: default

    integer ( int8  ) :: int_8
    integer ( int16 ) :: int_16
    integer ( int32 ) :: int_32
    integer ( int64 ) :: int_64

    integer, parameter :: aint = selected_int_kind ( INT8 )
    integer, parameter :: bint = selected_int_kind ( INT16 )
    integer, parameter :: cint = selected_int_kind ( INT32 )
    integer, parameter :: dint = selected_int_kind ( INT64 )

    integer ( aint ) :: int_a
    integer ( bint ) :: int_b
    integer ( cint ) :: int_c
    integer ( dint ) :: int_d

    character ( len = * ), parameter :: c_options = compiler_options( )
    character ( len = * ), parameter :: c_version = compiler_version( )
    character ( len = 255 )          :: cmd = " "

        call get_command ( cmd )

        write ( *, '(    "compiler version  = ", g0    )' ) c_version
        write ( *, '(    "compiler options  = ", g0    )' ) trim ( c_options )
        write ( *, '(    "execution command = ", g0, / )' ) trim ( cmd )

        write ( * , 100 ) 'default', sizeof ( default )

        write ( * , 100 ) 'int_8', sizeof ( int_8 )
        write ( * , 100 ) 'int_16', sizeof ( int_16 )
        write ( * , 100 ) 'int_32', sizeof ( int_32 )
        write ( * , 100 ) 'int_64', sizeof ( int_64 )

        write ( * , 100 ) 'int_a', sizeof ( int_a )
        write ( * , 100 ) 'int_b', sizeof ( int_b )
        write ( * , 100 ) 'int_c', sizeof ( int_c )
        write ( * , 100 ) 'int_d', sizeof ( int_d )

        write ( * , 110 ) 'aint', aint
        write ( * , 110 ) 'bint', bint
        write ( * , 110 ) 'cint', cint
        write ( * , 110 ) 'dint', dint

        write ( * , 110 ) 'selected_int_kind ( INT16 )', selected_int_kind ( INT16 )

  100   format ( "Number of bytes in type ", g0, " = ", g0 )
  110   format ( "Value of ", g0, " = ", g0 )

end program bytes
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isn't a bug.  The standards (Fortran 95 13.14.94, Fortran 2003 13.7.105 and Fortran 2008 13.7.146) have this to say about  `selected_int_kind(R)`:

> **Argument**. R shall be an integer scalar.
>
> **Result Value**. The result has a value equal to the value of the kind type parameter of an integer type that represents all values n in the range −10<sup>R</sup> < n < 10<sup>R</sup>, or if no such kind type parameter is available on the processor, the result is −1. If more than one kind type parameter meets the criterion, the value returned is the one with the smallest decimal exponent range, unless there are several such values, in which case the smallest of these kind values is returned.

This means, if `int16` happens to be `2` on your platform, `selected_int_kind(2)` will return the kind of the smallest integer kind capable of representing the range -100 to +100, which is a single byte with a storage size of 1, so the value of `int8` is returned.

The output from a simple program below should demonstrate how this works:

```
 Value of int8            1
 Value of int16           2
 Value of int32           4
 Value of int64           8
 Value of selected_int_kind(1)            1
 Value of selected_int_kind(2)            1
 Value of selected_int_kind(3)            2
 Value of selected_int_kind(4)            2
 Value of selected_int_kind(5)            4
 Value of selected_int_kind(6)            4
 Value of selected_int_kind(7)            4
 Value of selected_int_kind(8)            4
 Value of selected_int_kind(9)            4
 Value of selected_int_kind(10)            8
 Value of selected_int_kind(11)            8
 Value of selected_int_kind(12)            8
 Value of selected_int_kind(13)            8
 Value of selected_int_kind(14)            8
 Value of selected_int_kind(15)            8
 Value of selected_int_kind(16)            8
 Value of selected_int_kind(17)            8
 Value of selected_int_kind(18)            8
 Value of selected_int_kind(19)           16
 Value of selected_int_kind(20)           16
 Value of selected_int_kind(21)           16
 Value of selected_int_kind(22)           16

This file was compiled by GCC version 5.2.0 using the options -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -std=f2008
```

Comment: Great answer and nice demo.